# Metadata of avi files

Tags: mp3, metadata, avi

I used the **od** tool in Linux to look the metadata of mp3 files and avi files by using the command

`od -c filename.avi`

For mp3 files it is showing all the fields very properly even in sequence. But for avi files it is not showing the metadata fields.

Whether is there is any difference in the way the metadata fields are stored in avi and mp3 files?

Can somebody tell me some good way of extracting metadata fields of avi files.

Comment: See other solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899431/from-where-in-an-avi-file-can-i-extract-the-recorded-date/36900840#36900840

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU lib extractor might be good for what you're looking for:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libextractor/

Comment: I already tried libextractor .. for video files it is not working properly.